# Validating input parameters before insert in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that takes in an XML parameter and copies the values into a temporary table. Then the values are then validated to be sure all required data is submitted and actions are taken if the data is not "clean".  If that data is good I then go on and process a series business rules and ultimately insert into multiple tables from the temp table.

My question seems so obvious but I'm going to ask anyways. On my insert into the subsequent tables I use the values I stored in my temp table by directly selecting from it. Do I need to validate the values again to be sure we have no nulls?

```
DECLARE @col1Val AS INT
DECLARE @col2Val AS INT

SET @col1Val = (SELECT column1 FROM #TempTable)
SET @col2Val = (SELECT column2 FROM #TempTable)

INSERT INTO Table (column1, column2)
VALUES (@col1Val, @col2Val)
```

VS:

```
DECLARE @col1Val AS INT
DECLARE @col2Val AS INT

SET @col1Val = (SELECT column1 FROM #TempTable)
SET @col2Val = (SELECT column2 FROM #TempTable)

INSERT INTO Table (column1, column2)
VALUES (ISNULL(@col1Val, 0), ISNULL(@col2Val, 0))
```

Is it necessary to check those values for null and empty before inserting? I would assume its fair to say if I've validated everything already it would be a waste to validate it again on insert. I've already done null checks etc.

I'm not sure if this question belongs in code review, if so feel free to close it.

There will only be one row in this table.

Comment: will you have multiple rows in `#TempTable` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do as

```
INSERT INTO Table (column1, column2)
SELECT ISNULL(Column1, 0),
       ISNULL(Column2, 0)
FROM #TempTable;
-- Where if there is conditions
```

That if you want to check for `NULL`s and replace it with `0` instead, otherwise, you can simply insert the data as

```
INSERT INTO Table(Column1, Column2)
SELECT Column1,
       Column2
FROM #TempTable;
-- Where if there is conditions
```

There is no need to declare those variables, and also this part

```
SET @col1Val = (SELECT column1 FROM #TempTable)
SET @col2Val = (SELECT column2 FROM #TempTable)
```

is not what you think, it will work just when you have 1 row in the `#TempTable`, if this table has more than 1 row, then it will throw an error

> The subquery returned multiple values. This is not allowed when the subquery follows =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when it is used as an expression.

---

Update:

> I'm asking is if I've already done the validation on the temp table is it necessary to validate again when I select from it to do my insert?

If you *already check the data while you insert it into the `#TempTable` and you are sure there is no changes in the data after you insert it*, then you can simply insert the data directly, there is no need to check for `NULL`s twice.

Comment: There will only ever be one row in this temp table  sinc e the stored procedure only takes one record at a time   I guess what I'm asking is if I've already done the validation on the temp table is it necessary to validate again when I select from it to do my insert?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was after.  Appreciated